# mkfs.ext4 -m -T options

Tags: ext4, formatting

How can I find out if I formatted the drive with

`mkfs.ext4 -m 0 -T largefile4`

or without specifying the options -m and -T

`mkfs.ext4`

In other words how can I see what is the -m reserved-blocks-percentage and  -T usage-type of a formatted drive?

Comment: IIRC with the [`dumpe2fs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dumpe2fs) command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute as root:

```
dumpe2fs | less
```

There is a line `Reserved block count`, which tells how many blocks are reserved. Dividing `Reserved block count` by `Block count` gets you the percentage of reserved blocks.

The `-T` option selects which configuration to use from `/etc/mke2fs.conf`. The main setting that changes is the `inode_ratio`, which tells how much filesystem space one inode covers.

To get back to that number, one needs to do following steps:

1. Get block device size by running `df -k /path/to/filesystem`.
2. Take the value from `1K-blocks` column and multiply by 1024.
3. Run `dumpe2fs /path/to/filesystem | grep "Inode count"` to get the number of inodes on the filesystem.
4. Divide the value from step 2 by the value from step 3.

The result is a number close to 4194304, which is the `inode_ratio` specified for `largefile4` in `mke2fs.conf`, if the filesystem was created with `largefile4` option.

Comment: It returns:
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Journal features:         (none)

Comment: Sorry, I missed some points of the original question, I updated the answer.